# Writing USB udev rules based on vendorid, productid & usb bus information

Tags: linux, ubuntu, udev

I've got a few usb webcams, but unfortunately they have no serial numbers.
So upon boot they tend to switch device file names.

Since they'll always be in the same usb port I want to create a rule based on that.
But it's failing miserably.

Here's what I tried so far:

```
# /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-5.1:1.1/uevent
#SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="05e1", SYSFS{idProduct}=="0408", PLACE=="2-5.1", NAME="video98"
#SUBSYSTEM=="usb", PLACE=="2-5.1", NAME="video98"
#SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{busnum}="002", ATTR{devnum}="009", ATTR{idVendor}="05e1", NAME="video98"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{busnum}="002", ATTR{devpath}="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-5/2-5.1", ATTR{idVendor}="05e1", NAME="video98"

# /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-5.3:1.1/uevent
#SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{busnum}="002", ATTR{devnum}="010", ATTR{idVendor}="05e1", NAME="video99"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{busnum}="002", ATTR{devpath}="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-5/2-5.3", ATTR{idVendor}="05e1", NAME="video99"
```

So yeah, I've made a few attempts. I've seen that devnum also changes on boot, so I don't want to use that.

I actually just want to use the "2-5.3" and "2-5.1" thing. That's always the same. But how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done almost exactly this before, weirdly enough. Mine were external hard drives, but it shouldn't be any different for USB cameras. I used the SCSI bus addresses for the ports, which worked well.

I got my info using `lsscsi`, which will print something like the following for a USB device:

`[2:0:0:0]    disk    <descriptor>    <dev name>`

Then something similar the following rule should do what you want:

`SUBSYSTEM=="usb", KERNEL=="sd*1", KERNELS=="2:0:0:0", SYMLINK+="<label_1>"`